# How to print a text file which is the target of a .lnk file to the Powershell Console

Tags: .net, powershell, com

How do you print the text content of a file which is being linked to by a Shortcut file?

Answer (score 2):

I went and looked at the documentation:
[Creating .NET and COM Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/creating-.net-and-com-objects--new-object-?view=powershell-7.2).

This gave me the template for the commands needed to write the target file to the console.

How it is done:

```
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$lnk = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\whitequill\Documents\PowerShell\Profile.ps1.lnk")
Get-Content $lnk.TargetPath
```

This does NOT create a shortcut. For some reason, the method is called CreateShortcut to read or write a Shortcut file.
In my example, **Profile.ps1.lnk** is a shortcut I made previously.

Comment: One can probably change this to read other formats like binary files or sorts and pictures.  If someone has a way of doing so please add a comment or answer involving formats other than a text file.